# Switch system navigation programmatically

Tags: android, navigation, navigationbar, android-10.0, android-navigation-bar

is there a way to switch system navigation programmatically? I've been looking for an answer on google and some sites, but I didn't find some information about this.

Thanks!

[image: system navigation]